# Batch can't find .exe files inside C:\Program Files (x86)

Tags: windows, batch-file

This is the code i'm using:

```
cd "D:\HigherFolder\FolderX"
start executable1.exe

cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\FolderY\"
start executable2.exe

cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\FolderZ\bin\"
start executable3.exe

exit
```

I want to start one .exe after the another, or at the same time, but this does not work with executables 2 and 3; command prompt says it can't find the files and that i need to certify that their names are correct (which i did, multiple times).

Comment: If one of the answers helped please mark them as accepted with the small 'tick' under up/down votes on the answer.

Comment: Wrong default drive, `start C:executable2.exe` would be a workaround.  And certainly @Ken's answer.  Please close your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change it to `cd /d` on command #2. (You can add it to commands 1 & 3 also for safety.) Your code operates on two separate drives, but CD only changes directories on the current drive without the `/d` switch.

```
cd /d "D:\HigherFolder\FolderX"
start executable1.exe

cd /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\FolderY\"
start executable2.exe

cd /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\FolderZ\bin\"
start executable3.exe

exit
```

Run cd /? from a command prompt for more info. An excerpt shows:

> Use the /D switch to change current drive in addition to changing current
>   directory for a drive.